# Show Data on Google Map using C# / DataTable

Tags: c#, google-maps, foreach, datatable

what am I doing wrong? I'm trying to load Google Maps with data from the database and I am using the following code, but am having an error when I enter the foreach:
"An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in GMaps.dll but was not handled in user code" 
"Additional information: Latitude must be beetwen -90 and 90"

```
   if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        GLatLng mainLocation = new GLatLng(-18.8533, -41.9450);
        GMapMyFriends.setCenter(mainLocation, 15);

        XPinLetter xpinLetter = new XPinLetter(PinShapes.pin_star, "C", Color.Green, Color.White, Color.Chocolate);
        GMapMyFriends.Add(new GMarker(mainLocation, new GMarkerOptions(new GIcon(xpinLetter.ToString(), xpinLetter.Shadow()))));

        DataTable MyFriends = db.ExecuteSelect("SELECT lat ,lng FROM tblAdress;");

        PinIcon p;
        GMarker gm;
         foreach (DataRow dtRow in MyFriends.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn dc in MyFriends.Columns)
            {   p = new PinIcon(PinIcons.home, Color.Cyan);
                gm = new GMarker(new GLatLng(Convert.ToDouble(dtRow["lat"]), Convert.ToDouble(dtRow["lng"])),
                    new GMarkerOptions(new GIcon(p.ToString(), p.Shadow())));
           }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the values coming back from your database is either greater than 90 or less than -90. Create a breakpoint on your code and step through the values coming back from the database to determine which one.

You should also trap bad values and set them to something else (either don't display or default to some other value)

Comment: But the way I set my mainlocation(-18.8533, -41.9450), I think I'll never have those values(90 or less than -90)

Comment: I tried to insert into the database a latitude 90, but then error became "Additional information: Latitude must be beetwen -180 and 180"

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the "." by "," to accept the correct variable parameters
example
-18.8533 -18.8533 by substituting for the value of the variable is correct

hola
tienes que cambiar las "." por las  "," para que la variable acepte los parámetros correcto
ejemplo
sustituir -18.8533 por -18,8533 para que el valor de la variable sea correcto